# Plotly.js surface plot data formatting

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to plot a surface plot of a function by generating the points myself via a for loop. The graph however doesn't show up. I've read that the z entry in the data variable for surface plots has to be an array of arrays but even that hasn't made the plot show up.

```js
var zPts = [];
var xPts = [];
var yPts = [];

for(x=0; x<1; x+=0.01) {
  for (y=0; y<1; y+=0.01) {
  zPts.push([Math.sin(x*y)]);
  yPts.push(y);
  xPts.push(x);
  }
  }

var data = [{
    z: zPts,
    x: xPts,
    y: yPts,
    type: 'surface'
  }];
  
  var layout = {
    title: 'My Plot',
    autosize: false,  
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    margin: {
      l: 65,
      r: 50,
      b: 65,
      t: 90,
    }
  };
  
  Plotly.newPlot('theDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some messing around I've found that the following code produces the plots needed
with only the addition of 3 temporary array variables needed. I believe the correct formatting for the data is that the x, y and z arrays have to all be an array of arrays with each sub array being the same size for all 3.

```js
var zPts = []; 
var xPts = [];
var yPts = [];


for(x=0; x<10; x+=0.1) {
  let zTemp = [];
  let yTemp = [];
  let xTemp = [];
  for (y=0; y<10; y+=0.1) {
    zTemp.push(Math.sin(x)*Math.cos(y));
    yTemp.push(y);
    xTemp.push(x);
  }
  zPts.push(zTemp);
  yPts.push(yTemp);
  xPts.push(xTemp);
  }

var data = [{
    z: zPts,
    x: xPts,
    y: yPts,
    type: 'surface'
  }];
  
  var layout = {
    title: 'My Plot',
    autosize: false,  
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    margin: {
      l: 65,
      r: 50,
      b: 65,
      t: 90,
    }
  };
  
  Plotly.newPlot('theDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
```

Comment: could you help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66061112/show-only-min-max-and-median-in-boxplot-plotly-js